# Global Arthur packet consist of only globally generic representations?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, automorphic-forms

I would like to ask very stupid two questions to experts.

I am wondering whether every globally generic automorphic representation of unitary groups are contained some global Arthur packet associated to some A-parameter.

Conversely, I am also wondering whether global generic A-packet consists only globally generic automorphic representations.

If these two questions are right, then these consequences are the work of Mok and Kaletha, Shin, White, Minguez?

Thank you very much if you share your knowledge.

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) No, at least for L-packets there should be exactly 1 generic member of each tempered packet (on the quasi-split forms).  This is Shahidi's conjecture, and is not quite known even for unitary groups.  (And KMSW is neither complete nor unconditional yet)